# How to convert string to LiteDb.ObjectId and vise versa in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-core, litedb

```
public class TaskModel
{
   [BsonId]
   public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class TaskViewModel
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<TaskViewModel, TaskModel>()
            .ForMember(dest=>dest.Id,opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Id));
        CreateMap<TaskModel,TaskViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest=>dest.Id,opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Id));
    }  
}
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class TaskController : ControllerBase
{
    // POST: api/Task/Post
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromForm] TaskViewModel taskViewModel)
    {
        taskModel.Id = taskViewModel.Id;        //ERROR: Connot implicitly convert 'string' to 'LiteDB.ObjectId'
        taskModel.Name = taskViewModel.name
    }   
}
```

I have LiteDB.ObjectId = 602f9484a5a84e0bc31938a8, so I need convert LiteDB.ObjectId to string and vise cersa.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

*convert string to ObjectId*

```
taskModel.Id = new ObjectId (taskViewModel.Id);
```

*convert ObjectId to string*

```
 var id = taskModel.Id.ToString();
```

Comment: It is working fine for me. Thx again for your help!